# Google Bigquery Storage: DeadlineExceeded Error when reading to_dataframe

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, grpc

I am getting the following error when trying to run to_dataframe() method from Google BigQuery Storage Lib.

The full code is here:

```
import google.auth
import os
import time
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import bigquery_storage_v1beta1
import fastavro
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]='key.json'

credentials, your_project_id = google.auth.default(
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
)

bqstorageclient = bigquery_storage_v1beta1.BigQueryStorageClient(
    credentials=credentials
)

table = bigquery_storage_v1beta1.types.TableReference()
table.project_id = "bigquery-public-data"
table.dataset_id = "new_york_taxi_trips"
table.table_id = "tlc_yellow_trips_2018"

read_options = bigquery_storage_v1beta1.types.TableReadOptions()
read_options.row_restriction = 'pickup_location_id = "48"'
read_options.selected_fields.append("vendor_id")
read_options.selected_fields.append("passenger_count")
read_options.selected_fields.append("trip_distance")
read_options.selected_fields.append("rate_code")
read_options.selected_fields.append("store_and_fwd_flag")
read_options.selected_fields.append("payment_type")
read_options.selected_fields.append("fare_amount")
read_options.selected_fields.append("extra")
read_options.selected_fields.append("mta_tax")
read_options.selected_fields.append("tip_amount")
read_options.selected_fields.append("tolls_amount")
read_options.selected_fields.append("imp_surcharge")
read_options.selected_fields.append("total_amount")
read_options.selected_fields.append("pickup_location_id")
read_options.selected_fields.append("dropoff_location_id")

parent = "projects/{}".format(your_project_id)
session = bqstorageclient.create_read_session(
    table, parent, read_options=read_options
)

now=time.time()

stream = session.streams[0]
position = bigquery_storage_v1beta1.types.StreamPosition(stream=stream)
reader = bqstorageclient.read_rows(position)
dataframe = reader.to_dataframe(session)
```

I am using Conda on Windows 10. The versions of Google Libs are below:

```
google-api-core           1.14.2           py37h21ff451_0    conda-forge
google-api-core-grpc      1.14.2               h21ff451_0    conda-forge
google-api-python-client  1.7.11                     py_0    conda-forge
google-auth               1.6.3                      py_0    conda-forge
google-auth-httplib2      0.0.3                      py_2    conda-forge
google-cloud-bigquery     1.19.0                   py37_0    conda-forge
google-cloud-bigquery-storage 0.7.0                         0    conda-forge
google-cloud-bigquery-storage-core 0.7.0            py37h21ff451_0    conda-forge
google-cloud-core         1.0.3                      py_0    conda-forge
google-resumable-media    0.3.3                      py_0    conda-forge
googleapis-common-protos  1.6.0            py37h21ff451_0
grpcio                    1.16.1           py37h351948d_1
```

Here is the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_Rendezvous                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test101\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py in next(self)
     78         try:
---> 79             return six.next(self._wrapped)
     80         except grpc.RpcError as exc:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test101\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py in __next__(self)
    363     def __next__(self):
--> 364         return self._next()
    365 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test101\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py in _next(self)
    346             else:
--> 347                 raise self
    348             while True:

_Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
    details = "Deadline Exceeded"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1568284475.885000000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1017,"grpc_message":"Deadline Exceeded","grpc_status":4}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DeadlineExceeded                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-8e16e005ecd6> in <module>
     48 position = bigquery_storage_v1beta1.types.StreamPosition(stream=stream)
     49 reader = bqstorageclient.read_rows(position)
---> 50 dataframe = reader.to_dataframe(session)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test101\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery_storage_v1beta1\reader.py in to_dataframe(self, read_session, dtypes)
    220             raise ImportError(_PANDAS_REQUIRED)
    221 
--> 222         return self.rows(read_session).to_dataframe(dtypes=dtypes)
    223 
    224 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test101\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery_storage_v1beta1\reader.py in to_dataframe(self, dtypes)
    313 
    314         frames = []
--> 315         for page in self.pages:
    316             frames.append(page.to_dataframe(dtypes=dtypes))
    317         return pandas.concat(frames)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test101\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery_storage_v1beta1\reader.py in pages(self)
    261         # Each page is an iterator of rows. But also has num_items, remaining,
    262         # and to_dataframe.
--> 263         for message in self._reader:
    264             self._status = message.status
    265             yield ReadRowsPage(self._stream_parser, message)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test101\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery_storage_v1beta1\reader.py in __iter__(self)
    126         while True:
    127             try:
--> 128                 for message in self._wrapped:
    129                     rowcount = message.row_count
    130                     self._position.offset += rowcount

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test101\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py in next(self)
     79             return six.next(self._wrapped)
     80         except grpc.RpcError as exc:
---> 81             six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
     82 
     83     # Alias needed for Python 2/3 support.

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test101\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded
```

The code fails immediately with Deadline Exceeded error after I run this line `dataframe = reader.to_dataframe(session)`. The rest of code executes without errors.

I've also created issue on GitHub but didn't get any useful reply there: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/9135

I tried older versions of Google Libs. I have exactly the same issue on my another Windows PC (laptop with Windows 10). Everything works fine on Linux machines.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like it is specifically a bug to do with the Windows environment. I think your question on github will be the better resource unless someone comes across this with a Windows computer to test on.

Comment: Two things I would do to try and solve... add try/catch logic to catch/skip the exception.  My other idea is to add timer steps to each of those calls at the end...'deadline exceeded' sounds like it is expecting something to finish in a certain timeframe and it isn't.  This particular idea could mean that your `reader = bqstorageclient` has failed to 'finish' before you use it in the next statment.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this on my windows machine (created conda env, installed google-cloud-bigquery and google-cloud-bigquery-storage), so I would consider this a proper bug for the team to fix on GH.

Comment: @jagthebeetle thanks for trying to reproduce this and for commenting in github issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe (not sure) that this error means the request is surpassing the default timeout limit. If you look at [test_reader.py](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/ae2e7058e402c4c963bc4991af7cd5f2b2801cc9/bigquery_storage/tests/unit/test_reader.py) the comments seem to suggest that a retry won't occur if the Deadline Exception is raised.

'# Don't reconnect on DeadlineException. This allows user-specified timeouts'

You can override the default timeout by passing `read_rows` a manual `timeout` parameter in seconds:

```
reader = bqstorageclient.read_rows(position)
```

So I think it would look like this, although I don't know how large to make the timeout limit:

```
reader = bqstorageclient.read_rows(position, timeout=100)
```

See also line 99 of [client.py](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/91fcc6a6ab723e272e9619cbd1fb24c2349c1016/bigquery_storage/google/cloud/bigquery_storage_v1beta1/client.py) for discussion of the `read_rows` timeout parameter.

Comment: quite simple solution, but it works! thanks you, Matt

Comment: I have the same problem but with `list_rows` method in Windows 10, This solution not working for me.